# Login with authorization role based using web api asp.net mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I implemented a token authorization system on asp.net webapi with owin middleware,
i succefully can authenticate with rest client and obtain authorization token to call the apis.but if i use [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] with roles parameter, id doesn't recognize user's roles, i verified the database and the usersinroles is correctly filled.and i am not access this index method.

this is a code snippet

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] 
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    return View();
}
```

this is my ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs class.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{          
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));           
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
```

is there something else I need to add in here to allow for Roles or should it be somewhere else in the code. I'm not completely familiar with `WebApi`, any help is severely appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post but I am in the same boat now. I want to do AD authentication and role authorization between Web API 2 and Android client but the authorization is ot working. Can you help me, please?